# How to suppress "Syntax error" in Eclipse 4.7.3a

Tags: c++, eclipse, eclipse-cdt, c++17

[This std::visit example](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant/visit) is not understood by Eclipse CDT yet but it compiles fine with a C++17 compiler.

I mean these lines:

```
template<class... Ts> struct overloaded : Ts... { using Ts::operator()...; };
template<class... Ts> overloaded(Ts...) -> overloaded<Ts...>;
```

Eclipse marks these two lines and displays "*Syntax error*". I was digging through Eclipse settings but I don't find any `@suppress` directive which would simple suppress a "*Syntax error*".

**My question:**
Is the a way how to suppress a "*Syntax error*"?

---

The settings `Preferences | C/C++ | Code Analysis` contain these sections:

- *Coding Style*
- *Potential Programming Problems*
- *Security Vulnerabilities*
- *Syntax and Semantic Erros*

The last section contains a more detailed description of an error which can be disabled or suppressed.
Would this section contain "*Syntax Error*" as it is displayed in the editor then my question doesn't exist. Especially, knowing the CDT cannot be always up-to-date this would help.

Comment: Unless you want to change IDE, you unfortunately have to live with it until Eclipse is updated to handle the latest standard (which it unfortunately lags a bit now).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer from [HighCommander4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141719/highcommander4) disables - as I commented - all "*Syntax Error*" markers which is **not** intended.

So, for the moment there is no solution to achieve this.

I opened a [ticket](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=534913) as [HighCommander4](https://stackoverflow.com/users/141719/highcommander4) suggested and may be it will be implemented in one of the comming Eclipse updates.

Answer (score 1):

There is no mechanism to suppress an individual syntax error (`@suppress` is a mechanism specific to CodAn (code analysis) errors).

You could suppress all syntax errors by going to `Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Annotations`, selecting `C/C++ Indexer Markers` (this is the kind of marker created for syntax errors), and unchecking some or all of the check boxes there.

Comment: First sorry, I didn't mention it in the question but this is unfortunately not an option to me. The _pure_ Syntax error is not listed there which would make it possible to suppress it.

Comment: @AlBundy I'm not sure what you mean by "pure"

Comment: @AlBundy: It sounds to me like you're looking at a different preference page. You seem to be looking at `Preferences | C/C++ | Code Analysis`. I am saying to look at `Preferences | General | Editors | Text Editors | Annotations`.

Comment: Yes, I was mixing up two different points in my comment. Unchecking - as you suggested - some or all of the check boxes is not an option because then a _correct_ "Syntax Error" isn't marked as well. I want to suppress only for the **unrecognized C++17 code** the error marker as I  am doing it now extensively with the `@suppress("...")` directive. May be the Eclipse community can reconsider to add the _pure_ "Syntax Error" suppress possibility in one of the next updates as there are still lot of unsupported C++17 features which lead to many error markers.

Comment: @AlBundy: I agree that supporting `@suppress` for syntax errors is a reasonable enhancement request. Please feel free to [file a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=CDT) requesting that this be added.